# Is there a more succinct way to get the last number in my url?

Tags: javascript

So I currently pass two variables into the url for use on another page. I get the last variable (ie #12345) with location.hash. Then from the other part of the url (john%20jacob%202) all I need is the '2'. I've got it working but feel there must be a cleaner and succinct way to handle this. The (john%20jacob%202) will change all the time to have different string lengths.

```
url: http://localhost/index.html?john%20jacob%202?#12345

<script>
    var hashUrl = location.hash.replace("?","");

       // function here to use this data

    var fullUrl = window.location.href;
    var urlSplit = fullUrl.split('?');
    var justName = urlSplit[1];
    var nameSplit = justName.split('%20');
    var justNumber = nameSplit[2];

       // function here to use this data

</script>
```

Comment: A really quick one-liner could be: `url.split('?')[1].split('').pop()` // returns '2'

Comment: There would be if you used proper uri query param format. Could use [`Url.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Comment: @Stuart thanks works like a charm

Comment: Good stuff, shall i add it as an answer so we all get some internet points? :)

Comment: @Stuart yes please do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really quick one-liner could be something like:

```
let url = 'http://localhost/index.html?john%20jacob%202?#12345';

url.split('?')[1].split('').pop();

// returns '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
decodeURI(window.location.search).replace(/\D/g, '')
```

Since your `window.location.search` is URI encoded we start by decoding it. Then replace everything that is not a number with nothing. For your particular URL it will return `2`

---

**Edit for clarity**:

Your example location http://localhost/index.html?john%20jacob%202?#12345 consists of several parts, but the interesting one here is the part after the `?` and before the `#`.

In Javascript this interesting part, the query string (or `search`), is available through `window.location.search`. For your specific location `window.location.search` will return `?john%20jacob%202?`.

The `%20` is a URI encoded space. To decode (ie. remove) all the URI encodings I first run the `search` string through the decodeURI function. Then I replace everything that is not a number in that string with an empty string using a regular expression.

The regular expression `/\D/` matches any character that is not a number, and the `g` is a modifier specifying that I want to match everything (not just stop after the first match), resulting in `2`.

Comment: Works perfectly, very simple, but don't understand what is actually happening?

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. If there was a B instead of the number ie John Jacob B would this still work?

Comment: No, because this regex removes anything that is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are always after a tag, you could replace everything up until the "#"

```
url.replace(/^.+#/, '');
```

Alternatively, this regex will match the last numbers in your URL:

```
url.match(/(?<=\D)\d+$/);

//(positive look behind for any non-digit) one more digits until the end of the string
```